# How can i have custom fields on the posts page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, field

First I've created a home.php page to replace index.php and can add some custom fields on this new one and to have in it lastest 3 posts.

On home.php page I put:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'test', true); ?>"/>
```

but it doesn't works cause it tries get the post id and not the id of the page. If i put 18 (id of the page) directly it works, but i want it dinamicaly:

```
 <?php echo get_post_meta(18, 'test', true); ?>"/>
```

And this condition is **not** satisfied for test:

```
if($post->post_type == 'page'){
    echo 'This item is a page and the ID is: '.$post->ID;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heyo,

I think your problem might be that you should have that within a loop.
For example if you were displaying several post from a category and displaying each custom field it might look like this:

```
 <?php query_posts('cat=25&showposts=3'); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li class="homeblock" style="max-width:400px;">
        <span class="artist-name">  
    <?php $key='artist'; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?> 
</span>
    <div class="entry-thumbnail">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 
    </div>

    </li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Otherwise (not sure how your theme is set up), what you might have to do is edit content.php and add:

```
<?php $key='artist'; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ($post->post_type == 'page') {
    <?php echo get_post_meta($page_id, 'test', true); ?>
}
```

Hope this helps :)